# Expand the basis

Tags: linear-algebra

$W=\{(a,b,c) : a+b+c=0\}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Find a basis for $W$ and determine its dimension.

Expand the basis you have found in basis to a basis $\beta$ in $\Bbb R^3$ .

Comment: Welcome MathSE! You should show your previous attempt in your question so that one can help you.

Comment: Hint: $a+b+c=0$ can be written as $(a,b,c)\cdot(1,1,1)=0$. Does this suggest anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $W$ has all vectors of the form $(a,b,-b-a)$. If you can represent a vector $\overrightarrow{V}$ in this form, what does this mean about $\overrightarrow{V}$? Can you somehow break it down to a linear combination?

As for the second part, you already know that $\Bbb R^3$ has a dimension of 3. If you find a set of 3 vectors that's also linearly independent, you're done; You just need to find such a set that also contains your first basis.